# acceder a nodos y subnodos en xml para guardarlos en sql

Tags: c#, xml

Tengo un archivo xml(factura) del cual necesito mostrar en un grid todos los conceptos que contiene mas el impuesto de cada concepto, la estructura de mi xml es la siguiente:

```
<cfdi:Conceptos>
<cfdi:Concepto 
ClaveProdServ="43211509" 
NoIdentificacion="190199189355" 
Cantidad="1" 
ClaveUnidad="H87" 
Unidad="PZA" 
Descripcion="IPAD WI-FI 32GB GOLD       SF9FCV258MF3P" 
ValorUnitario="6206.12" 
Importe="6206.12" 
Descuento="0.00">
<cfdi:Impuestos>
<cfdi:Traslados>
<cfdi:Traslado 
Base="6206.12" 
Impuesto="002" 
TipoFactor="Tasa" 
TasaOCuota="0.160000" 
Importe="992.98" />
</cfdi:Traslados>
</cfdi:Impuestos>
</cfdi:Concepto>
<cfdi:Concepto 
ClaveProdServ="53121705" 
NoIdentificacion="848709080639" 
Cantidad="1" 
ClaveUnidad="H87" 
Unidad="PZA" 
Descripcion="BALANCE FOLIO - PRPLE/PNK IPAD" 
ValorUnitario="912.93" 
Importe="912.93" 
Descuento="0.00">
<cfdi:Impuestos>
<cfdi:Traslados>
<cfdi:Traslado 
Base="912.93" 
Impuesto="002" 
TipoFactor="Tasa" 
TasaOCuota="0.160000" 
Importe="146.07" />
</cfdi:Traslados>
</cfdi:Impuestos>
</cfdi:Concepto>
</cfdi:Conceptos>
```

hasta el momento solo puedo acceder a los nodos de manera individual pero no me sirve ya que requiero se muestre en la misma linea del grid el concepto con su impuesto, espero me puedan ayudar, de ante mano muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comparto un ejemplo, espero te sirva.

```
XNamespace nsCFDI33 = "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3";

var file = @"C:\Users\luis4\Downloads\0DEC50A1-6F24-499B-AB14-9C7F30313E0E.xml";

XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.Load(file);
StringReader streamXML = new StringReader(xmlDocument.OuterXml);
XDocument archivoXML = XDocument.Load(streamXML);

var conceptos = archivoXML.Descendants(nsCFDI33 + "Comprobante").Descendants(nsCFDI33 + "Conceptos").Elements();

foreach(var concepto in conceptos)
{
    var descripcion = concepto.Attributes().Where(x => x.Name.ToString().Equals("Descripcion")).Select(x => x.Value.ToString()).SingleOrDefault();
    var impuestosConceptos = concepto.Descendants(nsCFDI33 + "Impuestos").Descendants(nsCFDI33 + "Traslados").Elements();
    var importeImpuesto = impuestosConceptos.Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.Attributes().Where(x => x.Name.ToString().Equals("Importe")).Select(x => x.Value.ToString()).SingleOrDefault()));

    Console.WriteLine(descripcion + " - " + importeImpuesto);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: muchas gracias por responder Archer_A, estoy utilizando tu ejemplo solo que no estoy muy familiarizado con LinQ y de inicio me marca un error en esta linea ```var importeImpuesto = impuestosConceptos.Sum(x => Convert.ToDecimal(x.Attributes().Where(x => x.Name.ToString().Equals("Importe")).Select(x => x.Value.ToString()).SingleOrDefault())); ``` me dice que: Error Una variable local o un parámetro denominados 'x' no se pueden declarar en este ámbito porque ese nombre se está usando en un ámbito local envolvente para definir una variable, cambiè la x por c pero me trae el importe en 0

Comment: Listo Archer_A muchisimas gracias solo tuve que cambiar la linea que te mencionaba por ```var importeImpuesto = impuestosConceptos.Attributes().Where(x => x.Name.ToString().Equals("Importe")).Select(x => x.Value.ToString()).SingleOrDefault();``` y listo ya me trae el importe de impuesto por cada concepto

Comment: Perfecto, solo ten en cuenta que la linea que puse considera que un concepto puede tener mas de 1 impuesto, por eso hago el Sum, pero si tus conceptos unicamente van a traer 1 impuesto lo que hiciste te funcionara sin problemas